# Sitemap and static pages on Blogger

Tags: blogger

So Blogger now has static pages and this is all very nice. Unfortunately, these pages don't appear in the sitemap generated at `atom.xml` or `rss.xml` and there is no way to publish a file on Blogger within the same domain name.

How can the static pages get listed in a Blogger sitemap?

Answer (score 1):

Static pages <s>are not</s> should not go in the RSS as they lack published date and other items which a post has so that users syndicate to the feed (a static page should not be showing these items).

Now seeing that the only way to get the sitemap is using the RSS feed that leaves one in a conundrum.

Your only option would be to manually recreate it using a script or by hand to submit the sitemap.

If your static pages are not being updated frequently then you shouldn't have to worry about indexing.